# Is it possible to use Travis or Circle with a public repo not hosted on GitHub?

Tags: drupal, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I maintain an [open-source project which is hosted on Drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/project/realistic_dummy_content/git-instructions). I don't want to move it to GitHub because my users are on Drupal.org.

I would like to have Travis CI, Circle CI, or another continuous integration service run some tests on every push to the repo. From what I understand, only repos which are hosted on GitHub are available to these services.

What would be the best approach to make a repo not hosted on GitHub available to a CI service?

Thanks,

Albert.

Comment: Once adding "or another" it's a shopping question. But maybe there will be sufficient answers/directions anyway..

Answer (score 1):

Travis and Circle support only Github repositories.

Easiest step would be adding post-commit hook, that would mirror repository to Github.

I know some services that do have such an approach, e.g. Drupal itself: https://github.com/drupal/drupal